# When creating a dictionary in PowerShell are duplicate keys all accounted for?

Tags: powershell, dictionary

I'm looping through some files and pulling values into a dictionary around a ":" delimiter.

The data in the txt files looks like this:

```
AD ID: 9999
Ad Placement: Computers
Landing Page: www.something.com
Interests: this and that and this 
Interests: also this thing and one final thing
```

My script for creating a dictionary looks like the following:

```
$files = ls "*.txt" 
$dictionary = @{} 
[System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]$list = @() 

foreach ($f in $files) {
    $in = Get-Content -Raw $f
    $in.Split([Environment]::NewLine) | ForEach-Object {
        $key, $value = $_.Split(':')
        $dictionary[$key] = $value 
    }

    [void]$list.Add($dictionary['Ad ID'] + ',' + $dictionary['Ad Text'] + ',' +
        $dictionary['Ad Landing Page'] + ',' + $dictionary['Interests'])
}
```

That's the basic idea at least. I've gotten unpredictable results when I come across a file that has a key twice, as is the case in the entry in the sample data above called "Interests."

What occurs when adding dictionary items to a list from a file?

In the above example, what is the value of `$dictionary['interests']` as it goes through the script?

Comment: The question looks superfluous to me, what's the problem trying it by yourself?

Comment: what you are calling `dictionary` is a hashtable. the keys MUST be unique. so ... what do you mean by `unpredictable results`?

Comment: If you want to use a dictionary then use dictionaries constructor ```$d = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]]::new()```

Comment: What do you mean by "unpredictable results"? The code should predictively give you the values of the last occurrence of each unique key. And if a key is not present in an input file, the hashtable should retain the respective value from the previous file.

Comment: The unpredictable aspect was that I was finding that the 'interests' key would have a value equal to the first instance of interests in some files, and second instance of interests in others. I think it was an issue with using ConvertFrom-StringData as mentioned below. The text files were also non-uniform in structure so error could have been from how I was prepping text files (insertion of colons for delimiters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data can contain duplicate keys, you cannot use the [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

To get the data in a dictionary (hashtable) manually is not that hard to do and you can decide for yourself what to do with duplicate keys: either overwrite the values so the last entry found 'wins' or not:

```
# this decides which duplicate value you want to store in the hashtable
$allowOverwrite = $false

$hash = @{}
# get the content of the file as string array and loop through
Get-Content -Path 'THE FULL PATH AND FILENAME OF YOUR TEXTFILE' | ForEach-Object {
    if ( -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) {
        # split string to get the key and the value
        $key, $value = $_ -split ':', 2 | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }

        # if a key is found that already exists in the hashtable
        if ($hash.ContainsKey($key)) {
            # either overwrite the value 'Last-One-Wins'
            # or do nothing 'First-One-Wins'
            if ($allowOverwrite) { $hash[$key] = $value }
        }
        else {
            $hash[$key] = $value
        }
    }
}


$hash["interests"]
```

- shows "this and that and this" in case of `$allowOverwrite = $false`
- shows "also this thing and one final thing" in case of `$allowOverwrite = $true`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't ask this question very well, but this gets to the heart of what I was asking. Basically, can there be duplicate values in a hash table and how could one manipulate those duplicate values.

Comment: @MerrillCook Since by "values" you obviously mean "keys": no, the keys in a hashtable are always unique (that's an inherent property of this kind of datastructure). You cannot have two keys with the same name but different values. A key can point to an array instead of a scalar value, though.